# Make a condition on const wchar_t*

Tags: c++, pointers

how can i make a condition with const wchar_t*?I have tried
    
`const wchar_t* password
if (L"xyz" == password) 
{...}`

but it's not working

thank you

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcscmp or use `std::wstring`.

Comment: Compare the contents not the poniters

Comment: I want to compare contents not the pointers

Comment: @A.Adil So, do that? For future reference, "not working" is not useful problem description.

Comment: As stated above, your code just compares the addresses of the variables, so your if (L"xyz" == password) will always fail. If you want to see if the text is equal, you need to use wcscmp(L"xyz", password).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [wcscmp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731(v=vs.71).aspx)

```
const wchar_t* password = L"xyz";
if (wcscmp(password, L"xyz") == 0) {
    // Strings are identical
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing `L"xyz" == whatever` (or even the non-wide version, `"xyz" == whatever`) you are comparing pointers, not string contents.

E.g. say your variable `password` is stored at location `0x00100000` in memory, and the constant `L"xyz"` is stored at location `0x00200000`.  When you perform the equality test with the line `L"xyz" == password` what it is actually comparing is `0x00100000 == 0x00200000`, which is obviously never going to be true.

What you need to do is use the library function `wcscmp` to compare wide-character strings.  However, since this is tagged as C++, you should be using `std::wstring` and the overloaded `operator ==` unless you have a reason to be using C strings.  That may be where you're confused: when using `std::string` or `std::wstring` you *can* use `==` to compare strings because those classes overload the `==` operator so this code works just fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::wstring wstr = L"Hello World";
    if(wstr == L"Hello World")
    {
        std::wcout << wstr << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As a side note, you really shouldn't be using constants to store passwords in your program unless they're encrypted somehow.